# Angular : Directive code not rendering the template

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I simply cloned the [angular seed](https://github.com/angular/angular-seed) project and added a directive as shown below:

```
    .directive('dataGrid',function(){
    return{
        restrict: 'E',
        template : '<h1>HHHIII</h1>'
    }
})
```

But when I use the directive `<data-grid></data-grid>` the HTML content is not displayed. Can any one point out what I'm missing ?

And when I inspect the page in browser, here is what I see

```
<div ng-view="" class="ng-scope">
  <data-grid class="ng-scope"></data-grid>
</div>
```

Comment: try adding `replace: true`

Comment: check if directive is added to main module - angular won't report errors for unknown directives

Comment: OK I see you added directive inside ng-view, thats the problem, put directive usage inside one of the views that is rendered eg. view1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is the name of the directive. The prefix `data-` is used for HTML5 custom attributes. Renaming your directive should solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

`data-` is reserved name. Angular ignores it by HTML5 standard.
By prefixing `dataGrid` with custom string it started working:

```
app.directive('testDataGrid',function(){
  return{
      template: '<h1>HHHIII</h1>'
  }
});

<test-data-grid></test-data-grid>
```